Handle dependency in python file generated by SWIG
I have a swig generated python file like this :
from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info
if _swig_python_version_info < (2, 7, 0):
    raise RuntimeError("Python 2.7 or later required")

# Import the low-level C/C++ module
if __package__ or "." in __name__:
    from . import _FOO
else:
    import _FOO

Due to some reason which is not the context of this problem, I have a dependency that before import _FOO I need to have "import BAR" line. Otherwise the cpp library _FOO would not be loaded correctly.
I cannot find a simple directive in SWIG which can do this. I have tried writing many things like %pythoncode import BAR at the top of the SWIG interface (.i) file, still it only writes after this import _FOO line.
Please give me a solution to this.

Use the %pythonbegin directive to add code to the beginning of the Python code.

But why does it not by default do it at the beginning. Same thing for Perl does that correctly
